# Getting a XML-slice using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a XML file having the following structure:

```
A
|--- B
     |--- C
     |--- C
|--- B
     |--- C
|--- B
     |--- C
     |--- C
     |--- C
```

and try to serialize parts of it to a text file using XSLT.

I'm looping in a for-each-loop over all C-Elements. And now I would like to serialize the complete "slice" for the current C-Element. I'm using the serialize()-function, which works fine for the C-Element, but, of course, if I go up to to the A-Level I get the whole XML. Is there a way to serialize it, so that I get my C-Element, the corresponding B-Level and A-Level, but not the rest?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Show us your actual input, and the XSLT you've got so far. Also, the expected output

Comment: Wild guess, if you really use `serialize` which is part of XSLT/XPath 3 then you also have `snapshot` so you can use `//C!serialize(root(snapshot(.))`.

Comment: See also http://xslt-3-by-example.blogspot.de/2017/06/extracting-sub-trees-of-document-using.html.

Comment: snapshot was the perfect hint. Thanks!

Comment: I have written an answer with the `snapshot` hint so that you can mark your question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you mention `serialize` I assume you use an XSLT 3.0 processor where you then can also use the XSLT 3 `snapshot` function (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#func-snapshot) to get a copy of a subtree containing a `C` element with e.g. `//C!root(snapshot())` or if you want to serialize `//C!serialize(root(snapshot()))`.

See also http://xslt-3-by-example.blogspot.de/2017/06/extracting-sub-trees-of-document-using.html for an example using `snapshot` (though not with `serialize`).